# Allowing the user to update a CraftCMS pagination limit with listing filter options

Tags: forloop, pagination, loop, limit

I am building a pagination layout limiting the content to 10 because, well, it makes sense to break down large amounts of content to smaller chunks.

But as there is so much, a user might want to toggle how many they want to see. But because the pagination limit is done in the twig variables, is there a built in method for updating this on user interactions?

Standard CraftCMS pagination code:

```
{% paginate craft.entries.section(entry.slug).order('postDate desc').with: ['image'].limit(10) as pageInfo, pageItems %}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a form/a link with the limit and add the parameter in your `$_GET` request or as a [segment](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.request#segments) to your url. This is just an example how to use it.

```
How many Entries would you like to get?
<a href="/?limit=10">10</a>
<a href="/?limit=20">20</a>
<a href="/?limit=30">30</a>
```

Then you can fetch this parameter

```
{% set limit = craft.request.getQuery('limit', 10) %}
{% paginate craft.entries.section(entry.slug).order('postDate desc').with: ['image'].limit(limit) as pageInfo, pageItems %}
```

Of course you have to attach this parameter to your paginate links as well

```
{% if pageInfo.prevUrl %}<a href="{{ pageInfo.prevUrl }}?limit={{ limit }}">Previous Page</a>{% endif %}
```

There are definitely better solutions but they require more time and more effort and a plugin/php but this would be the easiest solution